Crop Bitmap with an overlayview - ID Card Capture
I'm developing a feature to take picture of id card, I'm drawing a rectangle view on preview view in camerax so users can fit card inside and capture image. What I want is to crop the card inside the frame and with the code below what I've done so far is to successfully crop top,left,right but the bottom still contains outside the rectangle, is anyone has done this feature before please give me some lead here, thank you in advance.
image of preview screen:

imageCapture.takePicture(
                outputOptions,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                    override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Image saved to ${uri.path}")
                        // Load the image and crop
                        val bitmap1 =
                            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(contentResolver.openInputStream(uri))
                        if (bitmap1 != null) {
                            // Get the rectangle's position on the screen
                            val bitmap = rotateBitmapIfRequired(bitmap1,uri)
                            val mat = Mat()
                            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat)
                            val location = IntArray(2)
                            cardFrameView.getLocationInWindow(location)
                            val scaleX = bitmap.width.toFloat() / previewView.width.toFloat()
                            val scaleY = bitmap.height.toFloat() / previewView.height.toFloat()

                            val x = (location[0] * scaleX).toInt()
                            val y = (location[1] * scaleY).toInt()
                            val rectWidth = (cardFrameView.width * scaleX).toInt()
                            val rectHeight = (cardFrameView.height * scaleY).toInt()
                            val rect = org.opencv.core.Rect(
                                x,
                                y,
                                (cardFrameView.width * scaleX).toInt(),
                                (cardFrameView.height * scaleY).toInt()
                            )

                            // Ensure the rect is within the bitmap's bounds
                            val validRect = org.opencv.core.Rect(
                                max(0, rect.x),
                                max(0, rect.y),
                                min(rectWidth, mat.width() - x),
                                min(rectHeight, mat.height() - y)
                            )
                            if (validRect.width > 0 && validRect.height > 0) {
                                val croppedMat = mat.submat(validRect)

                                // Convert croppedMat back to a Bitmap
                                val croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                    croppedMat.width(),
                                    croppedMat.height(),
                                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                                )
                                Utils.matToBitmap(croppedMat, croppedBitmap)

                                // Save the cropped image
                                saveCroppedImage(croppedBitmap)
                            } else {
                                Log.e(
                                    TAG,
                                    "Invalid crop dimensions: width=${rect.width}, height=${rect.height}"
                                )
                            }

                        }
                    }


what are we seeing? is that some wood texture, or is the preview display corrupted? [mre] required.

@ChristophRackwitz hi , this is the preview display of camerax in android, i want when i capture the picture it will automatically crop the image inside that rectangle frame
